# R/dygraphs Error: Unsupported type passed to argument 'data'

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am working with the R programming language.

I am following the tutorial here https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/ to make the following graph:

[image]

I tried to simulate some data for this example:

```
library(dygraphs)


set.seed(1)
date <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-01"), by = "month")
var1 <- rnorm(length(date), mean = 100, sd = 10)
var2 <- rnorm(length(date), mean = 50, sd = 5)
df <- data.frame(date, var1, var2)
```

Then, I tried to make this graph:

```
dygraph(df, main = "Stacked Graph") %>%
  dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
  dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

**But I get the following error:**

```
Error in dygraph(df, main = "Stacked Graph") : 
  Unsupported type passed to argument 'data'.
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

**Update:** I think I was able to figure it out:

```
library(xts)
df_xts <- xts(df[,-1], order.by = df$date)

dygraph(df_xts, main = "Stacked Graph") %>%
  dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
  dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the linked example, `lungDeaths` is a time series object, not a data frame. You can create `df` as follows:

```r
var1 <- ts(var1, start = 2010, frequency = 12)
var2 <- ts(var2, start = 2010, frequency = 12)
df <- cbind(var1, var2)
```

Then your plotting code produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Just a question - what if the series started at some arbitrary date, e.g. June 2010 - will your code still work?

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041654/r-stacked-graph-produces-different-colors-than-non-stacked