# R: Stacked Graph Produces Different Colors than Non-Stacked?

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data and graph:

```
library(dygraphs)

var1 = c(5,5,8,13,14,12,11,10,9,9,8,8)
var2 = c(13,13,22,30,35,31,25,24,20,20,20,21)

var1 <- ts(var1, start = 2010, frequency = 12)
var2 <- ts(var2, start = 2010, frequency = 12)

df = cbind(var1,var2)

dygraph(df, main = "Stacked Graph") %>%
  dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
  dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

[image]

**My Question:** When I remove the "stacked" option, the colors of the graph seem to change:

```
dygraph(df, main = "Graph") %>%
    dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
    dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
    dyOptions(stackedGraph = FALSE, fillGraph = TRUE) %>%
    dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

[image]

**Can someone please tell me why this is happening and what can I do to fix this (i.e. how can I make the colors in the second graph the same as the first graph)?**

Thanks!

**References:**

- [Why are the colors changing on my graph when I remove the grid lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77039848/why-are-the-colors-changing-on-my-graph-when-i-remove-the-grid-lines)

Comment: I would assume that `dygraph` uses transparency to distinguish between stacked and non-stacked plots. If the green color in the second example was the same solid green as in the first, it would give the impression of being stacked, when in fact the green values "lie under" the purple. So I think this is by design and should not be fixed. Perhaps a line graph would be more appropriate?

Comment: @neilfws: thank you so much for your reply! I had posted a similar question earlier today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77039848/why-are-the-colors-changing-on-my-graph-when-i-remove-the-grid-lines ... I was hoping to apply the logic provided there to solve my current question ... but I am not able to figure this out so far....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors look different, because when stacking is disabled
the coloring underneath the line goes all the way to the x-axis.
Therefore the filled areas for the two series overlap and there colors
get mixed due to the transparent nature of the fill.
You can turn-off the color transparency (`fillAlpha = 1`) to avoid color mixing.

```r
var1 = c(5,5,8,13,14,12,11,10,9,9,8,8)
var2 = c(13,13,22,30,35,31,25,24,20,20,20,21)

var1 <- ts(var1, start = 2010, frequency = 12)
var2 <- ts(var2, start = 2010, frequency = 12)

df = cbind(var1, var2)

library(dygraphs)

dygraph(df, main = "Graph") %>%
  dySeries("var1", label = "Var1", fillGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dySeries("var2", label = "Var2", fillGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = FALSE, fillAlpha = 1) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

[image]

To get the `stackedGraph` look and not display the
summed values, you can use this workaround (use with caution!):
Subtract var1 from var2 and plot as a stacked graph.

```r
df2 = cbind(var1, var2 = var2 - var1)

dygraph(df2, main = "Graph") %>%
  dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
  dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! is it possible to make the colors in the second graph the same as the first graph

Comment: I added a workaround to achieve the same colors to my answer.