# R: Labels on Graph Don't Match Data

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data:

```
library(dygraphs)

var1 = c(5,5,8,13,14,12,11,10,9,60, 50,40)
var2 = c(13,13,22,30,35,31,25,24,20,20,20,21)

var1 <- ts(var1, start = 2010, frequency = 12)
var2 <- ts(var2, start = 2010, frequency = 12)

df2 = cbind(var1, var2 = var2 - var1)
```

I then made the following stacked graph (based on the answer provided here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77041702/13203841):

```
dygraph(df2, main = "Graph") %>%
    dySeries("var1", label = "Var1") %>%
    dySeries("var2", label = "Var2") %>%
    dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE) %>%
    dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

[image]

**My Question:** I can see that the value of the green line on the y-axis DOES NOT match the value in the label (top right corner). **However, the value on the y-axis itself is correct.**

**What can I do to fix this?**

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you set stackedGraph = FALSE?

Comment: You are stacking the graph, so the value of var 1 is added to the value of var 2 in the plot. The text is showing you the actual value in the series, not the summed value. Are you sure you want a stacked chart?

Comment: @ADA: thank you for your reply! I deliberately reformatted the data so that the stacking and colors appear correctly

Comment: @MrFlick: thank you for your reply! I understand that the two values are being added together - this advice was given to me in a previous question such that I can keep the same color scheme.

Answer (score 5):

When you use `dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE)`, you enable the stacking of the series, and the label is showing the total (sum) of the two groups. In other words the label in the top right corner represents the sum of the stacked series rather than the individual values of `var2`.